# How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?

Tags: boot, boot-failure, boot-repair

When the bootloader (GRUB) is broken, I cannot access neither Ubuntu nor Windows.

I heard that an easy solution to fix this is to use the Boot-Repair tool from an Ubuntu liveCD (or liveUSB).

What are the steps to do this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

1. Insert or connect the Ubuntu live media (DVD or USB).
2. Find out how to [boot your computer from removable media](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD).

   Note that there is a [difference between booting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Identifying_if_the_computer_boots_the_Ubuntu_DVD_in_EFI_mode) of older computers (BIOS/MBR) and newer ones designed for Windows 8 and later releases (UEFI/GPT).

   Reboot the computer from live media and choose **Try Ubuntu** when asked.

   [image: Try Ubuntu]
3. Connect to the internet, then open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, paste the following commands and run them by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   sudo apt install software-properties-common; \
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"; \
   sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair; \
   sudo apt-get update; \
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
   ```

   > Note: You copy and run them all at once. If you want to run them individually just remove the trailing "`; \`".

   That's it, the Boot-Repair window will appear!

   [image: Boot-Repair main window]

#### Related:

- [What is a terminal and how do I open and use it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162)

Comment: It would be awesome to get this pre-installed on the live dvd's for future releases, because this is such a critical tool with the latest window$8 UEFI mess :(

Comment: you can vote for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/boot-repair/+bug/806291

Comment: This gives me an error "must run in 64 bit session"

Comment: John, that message indicates you need to use a 64bit Ubuntu disc.

Comment: What if I don't have internet on the PC I want to repair? How can I get Boot Repair on the live usb?

Comment: becko, you can use a disk (USB or CD/DVD) with Boot-Repair pre-installed. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A1st_option_:_get_a_disk_including_Boot-Repair