# How do I fix this problem with grub after installing Ubuntu server?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I've installed GRUB as part of the Installation process of Ubuntu Server 13.04 LTS edition. 
This is the screen that I get after booting from my hard drive:

```
GRUB: Loading.
Welcome to GRUB!

error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
grub rescue>
```

I tried installing Ubuntu Server (after numerous installs) on my partitioned hard drive. I remember them as sda5 and sda6. The install was to dual boot with Windows 7.
When I first install grub, I used the i386 iso, but after I found out that I could use the amd version to optimize, I installed that.

Now, grub has an error and I don't know what to do.

Almost all the help tell me to use a CD-ROM, but I used a flash drive. Now, I just want to either repair grub, or get rid of Ubuntu and grub entirely, as long as I can save my Windows7 partitioned on my sda1-3.

I'm very new, so step by step instructions help.

Comment: Please clarify (for others): 13.04 or 12.04 LTS ? There is no 13.04 LTS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install grub2. For doing that you need a LiveCD of Ubuntu. Then:

1- Boot with your LiveCD.

2- Open a terminal.

3- Determine the partition where your Ubuntu is. (let's say it's **sda6**)

`sudo fdisk -l`

4- Mount the drive with

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt/
```

5- Intall grub as root with

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda --root-directory=/mnt
```

6- Reboot your system.

Comment: I used a flash drive. Will that be my Live CD?

Comment: I tried, but it says permission denied.

Comment: The last command must be ran as root. I'm updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy and interactive way to fix the grub problem.. Using this method it will start reading all your boot partition and also you will be able to use any operating system. All operating system installed in your computer will be displayed in grub menu.

You have to follow these very simple steps..

1. Boot from LiveCD or your bootable USB, Select 'Try Ubuntu'.
2. Install boot-repair from console ( a good s/w to fix grub )

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
   ```
3. Run boot-repair from your system with alt+f2 or in a console

   ```
   boot-repair
   ```
4. When started select Option 'Recommended Repair' from out of two options:

   'Recommended Repair' & 'Advanced Options'.
5. Follow very easy onscreen instruction
6. Reboot your system and your menus should appear on the grub menu.

Reply if something goes wrong..