# How to reinstall/fix grub when Ubuntu is installed on a lvm

Tags: boot, grub2, mount

A few days ago, I shut down my server because I needed to physically move it, after which it wouldn't boot anymore. When starting up, I get the motherboard logo, but after that I just see a gray screen. [No "border" as some people see](https://linustechtips.com/topic/625821-ubuntu-gnome-boots-to-grey-screen-with-border/). [It doesn't boot after 6 minutes as some people say](https://askubuntu.com/a/1249914/1159881) on other forums that I've searched on to find a fix. No loading circle. Nothing but gray. No keyboard inputs worked.

In my search to fix it, someone on a similar forum post gave a [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelBoot) where they started thier fix by going into grub by booting and pressing shift while seeing the motherboard logo. So I did that, and it said `Launching/Starting (can't remember) grub..`. However after that I see nothing, which is contrary to `You should see the GRUB menu after the BIOS loads.` Just gray. So I assumed that grub was the problem.

In my search to fix grub, I found [this](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) link. In the first step, I need to mount my ubuntu install. However, my ubuntu install isn't a basic one.

When I installed Ubuntu, [I chose to setup the drive as an lvm](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/img_55035707bbd74.png?width=1198&trim=1,1&bg-color=000&pad=1,1) and later added a second drive to that. So on my system, I have two physical drives and one virtual drive (the lvm) on which Ubuntu is installed. The lvm is called "/dev/vgubuntu/root" but also "/dev/mapper-something" at some places. This isn't my flavor of technical knowledge so I don't understand everything. I just managed to set it up and it worked perfectly. Drive 1 is 1tb and drive 2 (added later to the lvm) is 750gb.

> Mount the partition your Ubuntu Installation is on. If you are not
> sure which it is, launch GParted (included in the Live CD) and find
> out. It is usually a EXT4 Partition. Replace the XY with the drive
> letter, and partition number, for example: sudo mount -t ext4
> /dev/sda1 /mnt.
>
> sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdXY /mnt

GParted only shows the first drive as /dev/sda5 but not the second. And when opening the gui-files thing when using a live-usb, it shows the lvm as /dev/md-0.

Doing the following shows an error:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda5 /mnt
#and this too
sudo mount -t "lvm2 pv" /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

`lvm2 pv` is what GParted showed for /dev/sda5. However, /dev/sda5 is not what I want to mount. It's the complete lvm, if I'm correct.

It's just becoming confusing and I don't know what I'm doing.

Simply said: Help! I don't know what I'm doing or what I need to do. I'm stuck!

P.S. yes I've booted a live usb and copied all important files and scripts to a usb and backed those up. So I COULD just reinstall ubuntu and install everything again. However, I have 1.5 tb of media that would take days to redownload and software that is working perfectly and was very hard to setup in such way. So I strongly prefer to fix it instead of just reinstalling ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried to [repair Grub from the Live USB](https://askubuntu.com/a/336733/1222991)?

Comment: @matigo yes. But it gave the error "The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware etc. etc." But when I reinstalled the iso on the usb using rufus, and chose "GPT", "UEFI (not CSM)", it wouldn't boot from the live usb. So I'm not able to use boot-repair.

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS amd64