# symbol 'grub_isprint' not found, error on boot, cannot use computer

Tags: installation, grub2, 13.10

I am installing Ubuntu 13.10 and the installer froze while logging in to Ubuntu one so I restarted and got "error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found"  so I booted up the live USB and ran "sudo grub-install /dev/sda --root-directory=/mnt" and then when I restarted I got this error "symbol 'grub_isprint' not found"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

I reported a similar issue here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1289017