# boot issue after cy with dd command (error : file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found)

Tags: boot, grub2, dd

I'm running Ubuntu through a 16GB USB having one partition for the OS and one dedicated for swap and all  is working well.
I wanted to make a copy of this usb key to a 32Gb key to increase the potential size.
I've made a dd command :

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`

It seems working well.
For what I've seen, the `dd` command copy the partition and also the MBR.
Anyway, with the new key, I got at the boot :

`(error : file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found).`

Could anyone help me...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found)