# Grub problems after upgrading Ubuntu from 12.04 -> 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, grub2

Recently I have upgraded my Ubuntu PC from 12.04 LTS to 14.04.1. After the first reboot, I was able to boot into rescue mode only (found similar problem here: [error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found)). I have upgraded the Grub using

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda --root-directory=/mnt
```

And now I have the following problem: I see the Grub menu, but the default entry is not working, and gave 2 errors

```
"file not found"
```

and

```
"you need to load kernel first"
```

But if I go to Advanced options - I see a long list of kernel versions to choose. When I choose "linux-image-3.11.0-15-generic" - it starts to boot.

Why is the latest "linux-image-3.13" is not loading? How can I repair it? And how to detect and remove all unused entries from the grub menu?

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get autoremove` is an easy way to remove old kernels, it also updates the grub entries.

I would try autoremove, reboot, check if the proper boot entries are available.

If the boot entry is still not available, try updating grub `update-grub`.

*Both commands require `sudo` powers*

Comment: Didn't help! After performing "apt-get autoremove" it was deleted many libraries. But the grub entries remained the same. And the problem that default (correct) Grub entry doesn't work!