# Cannot repair grub using, boot-repair fails without reason

Tags: 14.04, grub2, boot-repair, grub-efi

It just shows that error happened and gives link for log:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8585646/

Tried to disable/enable WinEFI backup, putting boot in Legacy and UEFI mode. In UEFI mode not worked at all as system was written in Legacy mode. In WinEFI gives same error.

What is possible reason for that?

Ubuntu is in /dev/sda9 partition.

System is 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04, LiveUSB is 64 bit (32 bit liveUSB not worked, gives link for 64 bit one)

If EFI mode is disabled (Legacy mode selected) why boot-repair is installing grub-efi ?

After reboot getting:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found
grub rescure>
```

Comment: I'll focus on the problem not the question. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found to fix the "error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can force Boot-Repair to install grub-pc (Legacy mode) by going to Boot-Repair advanced options --> GRUB location --> untick "Separate /boot/efi" --> Apply

Comment: Thanks, seems ok, but already made old ubuntu partition as /home partition and installed ubuntu to another one.