# Pointing Grub Rescue to the correct .mod

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grubrescue

I've borked my ubuntu installation.

It seems to have mixed up whether to use bios grub or efi grub.

When I get to `grub rescue`, I can find all the mod files I need at `(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub/x86_64-efi`

However, if I try to set prefix to this path, it always appends i386-pc to the path, so it can never find the normal.mod when I try to `insmod`.

So I end up getting `can't find file: (hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/i386-pc/normal.mod`

Rather frustrating. How can I convince this grub that i386-pc doesn't exist and it needs to look where I tell it to look? Haha.

I don't think this question is a duplicate, as I've been through the steps of all the other grub rescue answers and it's led me to this conundrum.

Oh, and I can't use my usb any more for some reason, or I'd just boot to live. So that's out. (Crashes to initramfs saying `can't find live medium`.)

Comment: When at grub rescure have you booted in BIOS mode? I think then the BIOS grub looks for a BIOS path. Make sure from UEFI you are booting in UEFI mode. Also more info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. The stupid and silly insmod command appends that crappy non-existent x86_64-efi folder

Comment: have you found a solution to this yet????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, GRUB can be very difficult to repair once things go "off the rails." You might want to consider using one of the [several EFI-based alternatives](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) instead. Most of them require at least some manual configuration, but that's likely to be easier than fixing GRUB. My own [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) requires no ongoing maintenance, so if it works initially, it should require little or no attention thereafter. (You can test it via a USB flash drive or CD-R before installing it to your hard disk, if you like.)