# I keep getting the same GRUB error?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Every time I start my computer, I encounter the error:
'/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod' not found.

Here is a screenshot of my hard drive partition:

[image]

I have no idea where I went wrong.

Comment: If the only problem is that error message, ignore it. GRUB sometimes displays errors but works normally otherwise. If you're having a problem beyond that error message, please say what it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Boot your Ubuntu system and then enter in the terminal:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Comment: Please add an explanation what this command does and why this could help to solve the problem. Thank you! :-)

Comment: This command wil reinstall the grub in a working ubuntu system.