# boot error I cannot get past

Tags: boot

When I bootup my PC I get this error:

```
        error: file'/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found
        Entering rescue mode...
        grub rescue>
```

But no matter what I do it will not move past this message. Any tips or ideas?

Comment: This link may help you
https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Create an Ubuntu LiveCD from this link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD

Boot into it. Use these commands to install `boot-repair`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

The boot-repair window will open up. DON'T TOUCH ANY OF THE SETTINGS. Click `Recommended Repair.`Wait patiently for it to finish, it will take a couple of minutes.

When the process is done, copy the URL somewhere.

Reboot, and hope it works! :D

If it does, your GRUB may look a little different.

If it does not use the URL they gave you to get some more information, as per this link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Best of luck!!