# Can't use Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on my machine but unfortunately I can't use it !

At first, I had this famous error :

`error: line '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found`

I looked on the Internet and I found that it is necessary to reinstall grub2.
After the installation, I found this screen:

[image: boot manager]

and when I click Ubuntu I got this error:

```
 error: unknown filesystem
 Entering rescue mode...
 grub rescue>
```

I tried to apply this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found) but it doesn't work!

Who has an idea please?

Comment: Use boot-repair to fix your bootloader https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several manipulations and searches, I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 by making a new partition of my hard disk ! (except that I lost my Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Download and run Gparted, you can download it from here:

http://gparted.org/download.php

It's a live ISO so burn to cd and run. Then delete all partitions on the hard drive. Then remove the Gparted from the dvd-rom and insert the Ubuntu install disc. Now run the Ubuntu install from scratch.

Comment: I really don't see how this is going to help, why gparted when the installer will format the drive anyway? and why a full reinstall just for a `grub-rescue` error?

Comment: Because, 1.) This is a new install and you have nothing to loose, 2.) Some partition might be hidden and starting with a blank disk might be the best idea and 3.) Sometimes a 20 minute install is simple quicker than googling or waiting for a reply for 3 days. But yes, formatting the drive with the installer will be a good second best.