# After installing Ubuntu 16.04LTS restart leads to Error: Grub Rescue screen

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

Two days ago I got a Install/Live DVD of Ubuntu. After Installing it the first time and restarting the computer I was hit with a "error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pv/normal.mod' not found." screen and when into grub rescue. 
I have tried all the steps i have found online to do and I can't seem to get this thing to boot. I have tried the troubleshooting from this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting . I have tried going into the Try Ubuntu session on the Live DVD and doing the boot repair but that didn't work either. I'm frustrated and stuck. Can anyone help? Please.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found

Comment: @AlcuinArundel Tried that and after entering "sudo grub-install /dev/sda --root-directory=/mnt" into the terminal I got a error message " grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists."

Comment: Here is a similar Problem: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=169124 - if this is the case i would recommend the gparted livecd: http://gparted.org/livecd.php - its like partition magic for free.

Answer (score 0):

You need a bootloader.

Use a LiveCD to boot into ubuntu and try reinstalling grub EDIT: or another bootloader /EDIT from there after upgrading the system to the newest version. I dont know if you have this boot option in the DVD of Ubuntu. Ultimate Boot CD has the option to boot installed OS.

http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/

After booting in your installed Ubuntu, follow the instructions here: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2/Installation/

or

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Post-Installation

There are also a number of other bootloaders you can use like LILO or leaving the ultimate boot cd in the drive, but i think grub is kind of the standard way.