# normal.mod not found by grub, boot-repair fails to repair

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader, grubrescue

I have a laptop ASUS, model G551J, with ubuntu 14.04.5 installed (64-bit
architecture). After running on it a USB live of Lubuntu, 32-bit, the laptop won't boot any more. A grub-rescue prompt turns up with the following error:

```
error:file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
```

I ran a USB live of ubuntu 14.04.5, and executed boot-repair, but it threw an error, with this log:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24279787/

There is a very similar question with a very good answer here:

[error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found)

But this question is more about why boot-repair failed to repair  this issue.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that running the usb live of Lubuntu had left the `normal.mod` file in `/boot/grub.bak/i386-pc/`. Knowing this and with the help of the answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266874/cant-solve-grub-rescue-problem) I was able to boot from `grub-rescue` prompt. During this process I had to delete a line in `/etc/fstab` created by boot-repair which intended to load a `boot/efi` partition, as boot-repair had asked me to create a small partition for the EFI table. This line was interrupting the boot process with this message:

```
The disk drive /boot/efi is not ready yet or not present
```

boot-repair had also uninstalled `grub-pc` and `grub-pc-bin`, and installed their counterparts `grub-efi`. This was making grub to look for an EFI table when the OS was configured to boot from BIOS. Reversing this situation fixed the problem, and after updating `grub2`now I can boot normally.

Bottom-line: don't use boot-repair.

Comment: Boot-repair has saved my systems a number of times.