# Repairing Grub not possible: stuck in grub rescue> error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue, boot-repair

I cloned my data to new hard disk named sda1 and then tried to repair grub by following the commands of website (https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/) and I got this message

---

Boot Info Script 8f991e4 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 25oct2017]

============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

=> Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

```
modules
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

=> No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       iso9660
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info: 
Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sdb1 is already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sdb1 busy
```

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  FAT16
Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdb2 starts 
                   at sector 0. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                   sdb2 starts at sector 3006684. According to the info 
                   in the boot sector, sdb2 has 0 sectors.
Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sdb1 is already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sdb1 busy
```

mount: /dev/sdb2 is already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sdb2 busy

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048   428,535,807   428,533,760  83 Linux

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.8 GiB, 4026531840 bytes, 7864320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *              0     3,100,799     3,100,800   0 Empty
/dev/sdb2           3,006,684     3,011,355         4,672  ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

/dev/sdb1 overlaps with /dev/sdb2

GUID Partition Table detected, but does not seem to be used.

Partition  Attrs   Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdb1   +  R              0     3,100,743     3,100,744 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sdb2   +  R      3,006,684     3,011,355         4,672 Data partition (Windows/Linux)

Attributes: R=Required, N=No Block IO, B=Legacy BIOS Bootable, +=More bits set

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs
/dev/sda1        4ed4332c-8f83-4650-aab4-999fec62dd50   ext4
/dev/sdb1        2017-08-01-11-51-33-00                 iso9660    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64
/dev/sdb2        398E-230F                              vfat

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov 22 13:13 ata-ST4000NM0165_ZAD27AZ8 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 22 13:13 ata-ST4000NM0165_ZAD27AZ8-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov 22 13:10 ata-hp_HLDS_DVDRW_GUD1N_B7GRVP9243628 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov 22 13:13 usb-Generic_Flash_Disk_86C72F75-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 22 13:13 usb-Generic_Flash_Disk_86C72F75-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 22 13:13 usb-Generic_Flash_Disk_86C72F75-0:0-part2 -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov 22 13:13 wwn-0x5000c500a456e8bf -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 22 13:13 wwn-0x5000c500a456e8bf-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov 22 13:10 wwn-0x5001480000000000 -> ../../sr0

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdb         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown MBR on /dev/sdb

00000000  45 52 08 00 00 00 90 90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ER..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  33 ed fa 8e d5 bc 00 7c  fb fc 66 31 db 66 31 c9  |3......|..f1.f1.|
00000030  66 53 66 51 06 57 8e dd  8e c5 52 be 00 7c bf 00  |fSfQ.W....R..|..|
00000040  06 b9 00 01 f3 a5 ea 4b  06 00 00 52 b4 41 bb aa  |.......K...R.A..|
00000050  55 31 c9 30 f6 f9 cd 13  72 16 81 fb 55 aa 75 10  |U1.0....r...U.u.|
00000060  83 e1 01 74 0b 66 c7 06  f1 06 b4 42 eb 15 eb 00  |...t.f.....B....|
00000070  5a 51 b4 08 cd 13 83 e1  3f 5b 51 0f b6 c6 40 50  |ZQ......?[Q...@P|
00000080  f7 e1 53 52 50 bb 00 7c  b9 04 00 66 a1 b0 07 e8  |..SRP..|...f....|
00000090  44 00 0f 82 80 00 66 40  80 c7 02 e2 f2 66 81 3e  |D.....f@.....f.>|
000000a0  40 7c fb c0 78 70 75 09  fa bc ec 7b ea 44 7c 00  |@|..xpu....{.D|.|
000000b0  00 e8 83 00 69 73 6f 6c  69 6e 75 78 2e 62 69 6e  |....isolinux.bin|
000000c0  20 6d 69 73 73 69 6e 67  20 6f 72 20 63 6f 72 72  | missing or corr|
000000d0  75 70 74 2e 0d 0a 66 60  66 31 d2 66 03 06 f8 7b  |upt...f`f1.f...{|
000000e0  66 13 16 fc 7b 66 52 66  50 06 53 6a 01 6a 10 89  |f...{fRfP.Sj.j..|
000000f0  e6 66 f7 36 e8 7b c0 e4  06 88 e1 88 c5 92 f6 36  |.f.6.{.........6|
00000100  ee 7b 88 c6 08 e1 41 b8  01 02 8a 16 f2 7b cd 13  |.{....A......{..|
00000110  8d 64 10 66 61 c3 e8 1e  00 4f 70 65 72 61 74 69  |.d.fa....Operati|
00000120  6e 67 20 73 79 73 74 65  6d 20 6c 6f 61 64 20 65  |ng system load e|
00000130  72 72 6f 72 2e 0d 0a 5e  ac b4 0e 8a 3e 62 04 b3  |rror...^....>b..|
00000140  07 cd 10 3c 0a 75 f1 cd  18 f4 eb fd 00 00 00 00  |...<.u..........|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000190  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  78 ac 2d 00 00 00 00 00  15 cd 66 0d 00 00 80 00  |x.-.......f.....|
000001c0  01 00 00 5e e0 fb 00 00  00 00 80 50 2f 00 00 fe  |...^.......P/...|
000001d0  ff ff ef fe ff ff dc e0  2d 00 40 12 00 00 00 00  |........-.@.....|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

/dev/sdb1: unknown GPT attributes
1000000000000001

/dev/sdb2: unknown GPT attributes
1000000000000001
Unknown BootLoader on sdb1

00000000  45 52 08 00 00 00 90 90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ER..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  33 ed fa 8e d5 bc 00 7c  fb fc 66 31 db 66 31 c9  |3......|..f1.f1.|
00000030  66 53 66 51 06 57 8e dd  8e c5 52 be 00 7c bf 00  |fSfQ.W....R..|..|
00000040  06 b9 00 01 f3 a5 ea 4b  06 00 00 52 b4 41 bb aa  |.......K...R.A..|
00000050  55 31 c9 30 f6 f9 cd 13  72 16 81 fb 55 aa 75 10  |U1.0....r...U.u.|
00000060  83 e1 01 74 0b 66 c7 06  f1 06 b4 42 eb 15 eb 00  |...t.f.....B....|
00000070  5a 51 b4 08 cd 13 83 e1  3f 5b 51 0f b6 c6 40 50  |ZQ......?[Q...@P|
00000080  f7 e1 53 52 50 bb 00 7c  b9 04 00 66 a1 b0 07 e8  |..SRP..|...f....|
00000090  44 00 0f 82 80 00 66 40  80 c7 02 e2 f2 66 81 3e  |D.....f@.....f.>|
000000a0  40 7c fb c0 78 70 75 09  fa bc ec 7b ea 44 7c 00  |@|..xpu....{.D|.|
000000b0  00 e8 83 00 69 73 6f 6c  69 6e 75 78 2e 62 69 6e  |....isolinux.bin|
000000c0  20 6d 69 73 73 69 6e 67  20 6f 72 20 63 6f 72 72  | missing or corr|
000000d0  75 70 74 2e 0d 0a 66 60  66 31 d2 66 03 06 f8 7b  |upt...f`f1.f...{|
000000e0  66 13 16 fc 7b 66 52 66  50 06 53 6a 01 6a 10 89  |f...{fRfP.Sj.j..|
000000f0  e6 66 f7 36 e8 7b c0 e4  06 88 e1 88 c5 92 f6 36  |.f.6.{.........6|
00000100  ee 7b 88 c6 08 e1 41 b8  01 02 8a 16 f2 7b cd 13  |.{....A......{..|
00000110  8d 64 10 66 61 c3 e8 1e  00 4f 70 65 72 61 74 69  |.d.fa....Operati|
00000120  6e 67 20 73 79 73 74 65  6d 20 6c 6f 61 64 20 65  |ng system load e|
00000130  72 72 6f 72 2e 0d 0a 5e  ac b4 0e 8a 3e 62 04 b3  |rror...^....>b..|
00000140  07 cd 10 3c 0a 75 f1 cd  18 f4 eb fd 00 00 00 00  |...<.u..........|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001b0  78 ac 2d 00 00 00 00 00  15 cd 66 0d 00 00 80 00  |x.-.......f.....|
000001c0  01 00 00 5e e0 fb 00 00  00 00 80 50 2f 00 00 fe  |...^.......P/...|
000001d0  ff ff ef fe ff ff dc e0  2d 00 40 12 00 00 00 00  |........-.@.....|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

File descriptor 9 (/proc/24659/mounts) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 29923: bash
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[64356]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 29923: bash

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 20171122_1313 ===================
boot-repair version : 4ppa65
boot-sav version : 4ppa65
boot-sav-extra version : 4ppa65
glade2script version : 3.2.3~ppa4
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1.  Check your device.map.
Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, xenial, Ubuntu, x86_64)
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
ls: cannot access '/home/usr/.config': No such file or directory

=================== os-prober:

=================== blkid:
/dev/sda1: UUID="4ed4332c-8f83-4650-aab4-999fec62dd50" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="28db28db-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="2017-08-01-11-51-33-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="0d66cd15" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="0d66cd15-01"
/dev/sdb2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="398E-230F" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0d66cd15-02"

The size of this disk is 3.7 TiB (4000787030016 bytes). DOS partition table format can not be used on drives for volumes larger than 2199023255040 bytes for 512-byte sectors. Use GUID partition table format (GPT).

=================== efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 000F
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0010,000F,0009,0011,000A,000E,0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007,0008,000B,0012
Boot0000  Startup Menu  FvVol(cdbb7b35-6833-4ed6-9ab2-57d2acddf6f0)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)....ISPH
Boot0001  System Information    FvVol(cdbb7b35-6833-4ed6-9ab2-57d2acddf6f0)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0002  Bios Setup    FvVol(cdbb7b35-6833-4ed6-9ab2-57d2acddf6f0)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0003  3rd Party Option ROM Management   FvVol(cdbb7b35-6833-4ed6-9ab2-57d2acddf6f0)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0004  System Diagnostics    FvVol(cdbb7b35-6833-4ed6-9ab2-57d2acddf6f0)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0005  System Diagnostics    FvVol(cdbb7b35-6833-4ed6-9ab2-57d2acddf6f0)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0006  System Diagnostics    FvVol(cdbb7b35-6833-4ed6-9ab2-57d2acddf6f0)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0007  System Diagnostics    FvVol(cdbb7b35-6833-4ed6-9ab2-57d2acddf6f0)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0008  Boot Menu FvVol(cdbb7b35-6833-4ed6-9ab2-57d2acddf6f0)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0009* Generic Mass Storage 86C72F75 BBS(USB,USB1,0x900)/PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)......ISPH
Boot000A* ST4000NM0165  BBS(HD,Harddisk1,0x0)/PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x11,0x4)......ISPH
Boot000B  Network Boot  FvVol(cdbb7b35-6833-4ed6-9ab2-57d2acddf6f0)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot000E* IBA GE Slot 00C8 v1550    BBS(Network,Network1,0x0)/PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x19,0x0)......ISPH
Boot000F* Generic Mass Storage 86C72F75 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(0,0)/USB(6,0)/USB(0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0010* hp HLDS DVDRW GUD1N   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(0,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot0011* hp HLDS DVDRW GUD1N   BBS(CDROM,CDROM1,0x400)/PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)......ISPH
Boot0012  HP Recovery   FvVol(cdbb7b35-6833-4ed6-9ab2-57d2acddf6f0)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH

=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled. (maybe sec-boot, Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com)

=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
sda1    : sda,  maybesepboot,   no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    notbiosboot, /mnt/boot-sav/sda1.

sda : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes

=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:4001GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA ST4000NM0165:;
1:1049kB:219GB:219GB:ext4::boot;

BYT;
/dev/sdb:4027MB:scsi:512:512:unknown:Generic Flash Disk:;

=================== lsblk:
KNAME TYPE FSTYPE     SIZE LABEL
sdb   disk iso9660    3.8G Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64
sdb2  part vfat       2.3M Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64
sdb1  part iso9660    1.5G Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64
sr0   rom            1024M
loop0 loop squashfs   1.4G
sda   disk            3.7T
sda1  part ext4     204.3G

KNAME ROTA RO RM STATE   MOUNTPOINT
sdb      1  0  1 running /cdrom
sdb2     1  0  1
sdb1     1  0  1
sr0      1  0  1 running
loop0    1  1  0         /rofs
sda      1  0  0 running
sda1     1  0  0         /mnt/boot-sav/sda1

=================== mount:
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8156332k,nr_inodes=2039083,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1634476k,mode=755)
/dev/sdb on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
aufs on / type aufs (rw,noatime,si=515d6a14e374f308)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=25,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=15044)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/999 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1634476k,mode=700,uid=999,gid=999)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=999,group_id=999)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset badblocks bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight integrity power queue range removable ro sda1 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sdb (filtered):  alignment_offset badblocks bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight integrity power queue range removable ro sdb1 sdb2 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset badblocks bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight integrity power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  autofs block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom cdrw char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency cuse disk dri drm_dp_aux0 drm_dp_aux1 drm_dp_aux2 dvd dvdrw ecryptfs fb0 fd full fuse hidraw0 hidraw1 hpet hugepages hwrng i2c-0 i2c-1 i2c-10 i2c-11 i2c-12 i2c-13 i2c-14 i2c-15 i2c-16 i2c-2 i2c-3 i2c-4 i2c-5 i2c-6 i2c-7 i2c-8 i2c-9 initctl input kmsg lightnvm log mapper mcelog mei0 mem memory_bandwidth mqueue net network_latency network_throughput null port ppp psaux ptmx ptp0 pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sda1 sdb sdb1 sdb2 sg0 sg1 sg2 shm snapshot snd sr0 stderr stdin stdout tpm0 uhid uinput urandom userio vfio vga_arbiter vhci vhost-net zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  9.6M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb       iso9660   1.5G  1.5G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs  1.5G  1.5G     0 100% /rofs
aufs           aufs      7.8G   80M  7.8G   1% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G  2.5M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G  256K  7.8G   1% /tmp
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  120K  1.6G   1% /run/user/999
/dev/sda1      ext4      202G   60M  191G   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1

=================== fdisk -l:
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1532116992 bytes, 2992416 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x28db28db

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 428535807 428533760 204.3G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 3.8 GiB, 4026531840 bytes, 7864320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0d66cd15

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          0 3100799 3100800  1.5G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       3006684 3011355    4672  2.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

No OS or WinEFI system

=================== Recommended repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will not act on the boot.

---

However, when I restart my computer then I stuck in grub rescue and I used following commands

grub rescue>     ls
   (hd0) (hd0,msdo1)
grub rescue>     set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
grub rescue>     set root=(hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue>     insmod normal
 error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found
grub rescue>     set prefix=(hd0)/boot/grub
grub rescue>     set root=(hd0)
grub rescue>     insmod normal
error: unkown filesystem

Guys,  It has been three days I am trying to resolve this issue but don't know how! Can anyone faced similar issue and able to solve it? Please help me.

Comment: I tried installing grub2 and i messed up... It has coincidently been 3 days for me too... I also got the same grub rescue terminal. Until now I was booting using the boot repair disk. The iso i downloaded from here ( https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/ ) and followed the same steps as you mentioned in the last para.. And a few minutes I followed the steps from this website ( http://linuxpitstop.com/repair-grub-boot-loader-on-ubuntu-linux/ ) and everything is up and running... But the things dont seem to be working for you.. as a temp solution try booting from USB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found)