# error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found ans filesystem unknown, Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: boot, command-line, dual-boot, partitioning, grubrescue

I run in a lot of trouble with my laptop. I am using an Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga and run in a lot of trouble after trying to install an Ubuntu/Windows 10 Dual Boot. I had an working Ubuntu installation but Windows did not wanted to boot anymore (also not from an usb recovery image as temporary boot). So I used a gparted live image to format my ubuntu partition hoping to get a clear drive to install windows and ubuntu from the ground up again.

Now I only get this during start up and even my gparted stick as live boot is not working anymore. It just gets back to the table with temporary start devices. I would be enourmsly gratefull if you could help me to get my Thinkpad back on track so I can install a clear windows or Ubuntu image from usb.

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/nomral.mod' not found
Entering rescue mode…
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,gpt7) (hd0,gpt6) (hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
grub rescue> ls (hd0)
(hd0): Filesystem is unknown
```

Thank you so much for your help.
Piet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna have to locate where the normal.mod file is. Try ls (hd0,gpt1)/, (hd0,gpt2)/, (hd0,gp3)/ and so on. There should be a boot/grub/i386-pc folder inside one of those. Let's suppose it is inside (hd0,gpt2), so if you run the command ls (hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub/i386-pc you'll see over a hundred modules on your screen. The normal.mod file should be there amongst them. Now run the command set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub/i386-pc, so grub will know where the file is. At last, run the command insmod normal and then run normal.

If you get an error message when running insmod normal like "error: file '/boot/boot/grub/i386-pc/nomral.mod' not found". Notice that, for some reason beyond my knowledge, the boot folder appears twice. In this case, just rerun the command set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/grub/i386-pc (without the boot folder).

If your root folder is located in a different partition, like (hd0,gpt3), you should make sure grub knows where to find it (though it is usually not a problem), run set root=(hd0,gpt3) and you're all set.

At last, if the problem persists every time you turn on your computer, you can simply create a symbolic link of the boot folder. I, for instance, had to create a boot folder inside the regular boot folder and then linked grub inside it, so I had /boot/boot/grub/i386-pc. For some reason that was where grub was trying to find the file. Oh! Don't move the file, create a link, so whenever grub is updated you won't miss anything.

Any questions or further issues, just ask!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your kind response. I tried "ls (hd0)", "ls (hd0,gpt1)" and so on for all the filesystems. For all of them, exept for (hd0,gpt7), I get the error "Filesystem unkown". For "ls (hd0,gpt7)" I get the response "(hd0,gpt7): Filesystem is ext2.". Unfortnatley I cant find any /boot/ folder or any file at all there. Thanks for any further help :)

Comment: But did you also run "ls (hd0,gpt7)/boot"? It looks like that is the right partition. And don't forget to add the '/' at the end, like "ls (hd0,gpt1)/" or "ls (hd0,gpt2)/"