# Is it ok to delete the contents of var/log

Tags: 19.10, log

var/log is huge: 4.6GB+. Is it ok to just delete all this stuff? Will it mess up my computer?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138180/can-i-delete-var-log-files-because-of-low-root-space-in-ubuntu

Comment: oops I even answered that one :D