# Not Booting on anything after uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

**[Sorry for my bad english]**

I installed Ubuntu just to see how it is with full installation. I installed through Rufus on an external USB.

But after 3/4 days of no game was working on that OS I decided to install Windows back but it didn't work. It was showing twice the green color on the USB then stops. I wait few seconds and some strange lines appear on screen. If I press ANY key it just restarts and starts again.

If I try to boot from the internal SSD, I am stuck at:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod'
entering rescue mode
```

I've tried some of the
[error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found)

It wasn't helpful at all and now this is my last thing:

What happened that I can no longer boot from USB? Why it does that?

Edit-1:

Even earlier when I had the Ubuntu OS it was no longer booting to windows installer when I had Windows on USB.

Image booting nowhere:

[image]

Edit-2: I am a new user of Ubuntu. I don't know that much about it.

Edit-3: I tried F10-F12, but I Still get the same screen. See above.

Edit-4: I used UNetBootin to to make a new bootable Ubuntu USB. After I plug it into the laptop and boot into it it says "missing operating system."

Comment: If your question is how to install Windows on your computer, this is not the place to ask that.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question so that it describes the problem you're having. You will not attract knowledgeable people with a meaningless title. While you're at it, edit the paragraph to include punctuation. No one can read it like that.

Comment: If you just erased Ubuntu and didn't run anything else to edit the bootloader, you're not going to be able to boot any system.  If the question though is "How do I get back into booting into the USB", that's a BIOS settings thing, you have to set your bootable media as the first thing to boot to rather than the inbuilt hard drive.

Comment: It does boot into usb it flicker twice the usb then i wait few seconds then appear some strange lines on display and if i press any key it just restart and starts again.

Comment: A UEFI system (standard last 10 years), has a boot menu (some key at power-up like f12 or f10) which should allow you to skip grub and select the Windows bootloader.  Installing to an external USB (from an install media USB) splits grub across the internal and exteral disks (see launchpad bugs 1396379,1173457 -- works until you remove the external disk (or erase Ubuntu) , then grub fails.  Boot Win, fix the efi bootorder to remove grub.

Comment: F10 goes to boot mode and from there isn't much to do since it shows everything the ssd , hdd , usb , realtek and thats all , F12 goes to something strange that it says that i need to put boot media which i have usb on first but its the same thing.

Comment: See the question [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu) and read all the answers. Make sure the USB you created works on another computer.