# Grub rescue does not open the boot folder

Tags: boot, grub2, external-hdd, grubrescue, usb-installation

I recently installed Linux Ubuntu 22.04 on an external SSD (through a USB memory, with Rufus)

When start I find this:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found 
Entering rescue mode 
grub rescue>
```

I start to investigate where the file is

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found 
Entering rescue mode 
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
grub rescue> ls (hd0)
(hd0): Filesystem is unknown.
grub rescue> ls (hd0,gpt2)
(hd0,gpt2): Filesystem is unknown.
grub rescue> ls (hd0,gpt1)
(hd0,gpt1): Filesystem is unknown.
grub rescue> ls (hd0,gpt3)
(hd0,gpt3): Filesystem is ext2.
grub rescue> ls (hd0,gpt3)/
./ ../ lost+found/ boot/ swapfile etc/ media/ var/ bin dev/ home/ lib lib32 lib64 libx32 mnt/ opt/ proc/ root/ run/ sbin snap/ srv/ sys/ tmp/ usr/ cdrom/
grub rescue> ls (hd0,gpt3)/boot/

grub rescue> ls (hd0,gpt3)/boot/grub/

error: file '/boot/grub/' not found.
grub rescue> ls (hd0,gpt3)/grub/

error: file '/grub/' not found.
```

Using "Try Ubuntu" of the USB memory I can access the SSD and find the path specified above (`/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod`)

Why can't Grub Rescue find it?

Notes:

BIOS or UEFi?
I accessed the BIOS and not found a mention of UEFI (It is a low cost desktop PC from 2011).

[image]

Hardware?
the motherboard is a MSI NF725M-P43

[image]

The SSD is Samsung M3 Portable 1TB

Comment: look at this question and answers https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &

Comment: I try use the Boot Repair with the installer in the usb memory. But i have this error:  "The current sessions in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CS/Legacy mode in your UEF firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-UsB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot Repair
Disk-54bit (wwnw.sourceforge.net/p/bootrepair<d), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode. This will enable this Feature"  
But in the bios I could not find any function of "Legacy",  "Secure Boot" or similar

Comment: Hello, I was finally able to solve the problem by installing Ubuntu and doing the partitions manually.
(I used the automatic installation before)
I did this: /boot 1 GB, /efi 1 GB, /swap 8 GB (double the ram), / (root) 100 GB, /home rest (approx 890 GB)