# Ubuntu 13.04 not recognized as Bootable after installation

Tags: installation, boot, 13.04, uefi

I managed to successfully install Ubuntu 13.04; however after restarting, I found that the installation was unbootable.There was no error message --there was simply no option to boot from my hard drive.

After the failure I sucessfully reinstalled 12.04 which worked just fine.The 13.04 beta release and 12.10 have also installed successfully in the past, but 13.04 final just completely fails to boot at all.

I have a modern computer with uefi boot capabilities (can switch from bios to UEFI).Ubuntu 12.10 will only load correctly in UEFI mode, if that helps diagnose the issue.

I am also installing using a basic DVD, no flash drives. So that should rule out any issue there.

Whatever it is something that changed between the beta release and the final version have rendered my computer useless.

My specs are the following (from invoice)

1x Sager NP9150 / Clevo P150EM

```
Display: 15.6" FHD 16:9 "Matte Type" Super Clear Ultra Bright LED Anti-Glare Sager Screen w/ 95% NTSC Color Gamut (1920x1080) (SKU - S1X301)
Processor: Sager - 3rd Generation Intel® Ivy Bridge Core™ i7-3840QM (2.8GHz - 3.8GHz, 8MB Intel® Smart Cache, 45W Max TDP) (SKU - S2R203)
Thermal Compound: -Stock OEM Thermal Compound
Graphics Video Card: nVidia GeForce GTX 670MX 3,072MB PCI-Express GDDR5 DX11 with Optimus™ Technology [User Upgradeable] (SKU – S3R517)
Copper Cooling Upgrade: No Copper Cooling Upgrade
External Display Video Adapters: No Video Adapter
External Mobile Display: No External Mobile Display
Ram: 32GB - DDR3 1600MHz Dual Channel Memory (4 SODIMMS) (Windows 7 Pro OS Required) (SKU - S4T844P)
mSATA SSD Drive ( Slot 1 ): No mSATA SSD
Primary Hard Drive: 512GB Crucial M4 Series Solid State Drive [SSD2 Serial-ATA III] (SKU – S5R063)
Optical Drive Bay: Combo Dual Layer SuperMulti DVDRW/CDRW Drive w/ Software (When selecting a Hard Drive in the Optical Bay, No Optical Drive is Included) (SKU - S7R455)
Optical Drive Bay Hard Drive Caddy: Sager - Optical Bay Hard Drive Caddy (Caddy Only) Used For Installing Your Own Hard Drive (Optical Drive Bay remains as selected)
Memory Card Reader: Internal 9-in-1 Card Reader (MMC/RSMMC/SD/Mini SD/SDHC/SDXC/MS/MS Pro/MS Duo)
Bluetooth: Bluetooth Included With select wireless cards only (See “Wireless Network” Section Below)
Wireless Network: Sager - Intel® Advanced-N 6235 - 802.11A/B/G/N Wireless LAN Module + Bluetooth™ 4.0 (SKU - S8R111)
Wireless Network Accessories: No Network Accessory
Camera: Built in 2.0 Megapixel Camera
Sound Card: Sound Blaster Compatible 3D Audio - Included
Battery: Smart Li-ion Battery (8-Cell)
Fingerprint Reader: Integrated Fingerprint Reader
Keyboard (Internal - Laptop): Standard Sager/Clevo Non Chiclet Backlit Keyboard
Operating System: No Operating System Standard - Drivers & Utility Software Only
```

I much prefer using Ubuntu over Windows but it drives me crazy when my OS inexplicably just fails to boot for no clear reason after a perfectly good installation --especially when it booted just fine in the beta!

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from a live CD and post a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file that it generates.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same situation because the grub bootloader wasn't installed correctly, so it booted into windows directly.

I booted from the DVD or USB, chose *Try Ubuntu*, and installed boot repair by typing these into a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Then I started boot repair and did the recommended repair.

See [How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)