# grub rescue prompt after installing grub into sdb

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu Minimal 12.04 LTS from USB. Everything was OK. But, when I try to install Grub into `/dev/sda`, the installation stops with a "fatal error".

So, I just entered `/dev/sdb` (just tried), Grub got installed without any problem in `/dev/sdb`.

Then, the installation finished without any problem. But after restart, it says 'grub rescue'.

I had only 1 hard drive. So what is `sdb`? I thought, USB drive was `sda`, and my hard drive `sdb`. Is it possible?

How can I fix it?

**UPDATE 1**
I tried Boot Repair, but it didn't work out.
Here is my Boot Info Summary by "Boot Repair".
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6433404

Answer (score 1):

> So what is sdb?

I'm afraid that you installed GRUB in your USB.

> I thought, USB drive was sda, and my hard drive sdb. Is it possible?

Not always. You had to check first using `fdisk -l`.

> How can I fix it?

With the little information you supplied, I'm afraid that your disk (or just the MBR) is badly damaged. Normally, the GRUB installation are flawless, unless you:

1. Haven't shutdown Windows or any other installed OS.
2. Have a dirty NTFS partition.
3. The disk MBR is damaged.

I recommend you to get a Live system (instead the minimal) and try to repair your GRUB using [`boot-repair`](https://askubuntu.com/q/226061/169736).

Comment: @Braiaim
Thank you for replying. I tried boot-repair. First, I run Recommended repair. I didn't work out. After that, I selected Advanced Options. Then, I checked "Purge GRUB before reinstall it" and "ATA Disk Support"(because it says "solves the [out of disk] error"). But it didn't help me. Still got "out of disk" error, and "no device connected".

I have Boot Info Summary. Can you inspect it for me? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6433404

Thanks

Comment: @Robert3000 Can you take an image of this "out of disk"? Also, did you reconfigured the BIOS to boot from disk again?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to run a live cd of ubuntu and install boot-repair.
Open the terminal and copy and paste the following command:

> sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

After successfully adding and updating the repository type the following command:

> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

There you can solve your issues related to boot.