# Dual boot with windows 7 no boot options

Tags: boot, windows

I used a live cd to install ubuntu 12, it went well and told me to remove the install device and reboot. 
But it just boots win7, i get no option to launch ubuntu. 
If there are more informations needed, i'll provide them.

Comment: Information about your setup would be useful here- for example, do you have multiple disks or multiple partitions on one disk?  If you have multiple disks, which one did you put GRUB on?

Comment: It sounds as though GRUB has not been installed correctly. You should be able to fix this with Boot-Repair from your Live CD. You can find [good instructions on this site](http://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc).

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you need a boot loader or manager. I have always screwed up dual boot, and have had great success with rEFInd. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/index.html