# I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS with a dual boot of Windows 7, Can I reinstall Windows 7, without changing partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation

I initially had Windows 7 as my primary operating system. I decided to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as a dual boot. However, I realized that my Windows 7 OS wasn't installed properly (not because of Ubuntu). I already created partition sizes for both OS's. Is it possible to reinstall Windows 7 without having to chnage around my Ubuntu setup?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer, no, Windows will nuke your boot loader. To repair, check any of those answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Windows 7 will let you choose a partition to install itself into during the installation procedure. Simply choose your current Windows partition.

However, the Windows installation procedure will overwrite your MBR where grub is installed. This means that you will not be able to boot into your Linux system after the Windows installation; your PC will always boot Windows. Don't worry, though. Your Linux is still there, you're simply missing the option to boot it. All you will have to do at that point is use an Ubuntu Live CD or USB, and reinstall grub using a tool such as `BootRepair`. This will enable you to dual-boot again.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/226064/223688) for instructions on how to repair your dual-boot functionality using an Ubuntu Live system.

Comment: is the "Live CD" the same as the dvd I used to install Ubuntu? and Thanks

Comment: yes, that's it. :)