# I am STILL having issues with GParted and partitioning this HDD

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

So a few people have already told me a few great answers that have sent me in the right directions but i am fairly new to Linux so it is a bit difficult to me ): . I have an Acer that **ORIGINALLY** had Ubuntu on it. I partitioned it (didnt back it up like a jacka**) however the windows booted up fine. Now, however, it seems as though neither Win7, nor Ubuntu want to boot. I have Win7 in Gparted set to my main partition as NTSF and it is taking up more space than Ubuntu since i will primarily be using Windows. Someone told me that Ubuntu needs to be set to an ext2 File system. After I apply the changes, is that all that i will need to do? please help. I really need to finish this up quickly ): i wish that i was more proficient in Linux ): oh and I am unable to boot into Ubuntu now. I am only able to boot Windows if i have a bootable disk in my CD/DVD drive. HOWEVER, it says that both partitions are still there and functioning. This is what it looks like as of now (i have no internet so pls excuse the photo)

[image: snap]

Comment: I've posted an answer below assuming that you installed Windows which caused the problem.. but as you say _"..someone told me that Ubuntu needs to be set to an ext2 file system"_ I do suspect you've possibly re-formatted `/dev/sda1` - the Ubuntu partition to ext2! Have you? If so, you'll have to get Ubuntu bootable media to install Ubuntu in your system...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install windows on a computer that already has a non-Windows OS running and expect it to work (with notable exception of Apple's Boot Camp).

The best option IMO is that you get Windows working first by fixing the MBR. Looks like the MBR is hosed.

Once you can boot in Windows, you can reinstall Ubuntu and fix the partition issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That sounds like an easier and quicker fix than what i've been trying tbh. thanks pal (:

Comment: Hope this helps you. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

If your Ubuntu files are fine, and that the problem is just due to the overwritten bootloader, you can use [Boor-Repair disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) to fix it.

[How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)

After getting it installed, start Boot-Repair and begin the rescue.

[image: snap0]

In **Advanced options** of the **[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)** utility/disc, choose to *Restore MBR* under the *Main options*. Next under *MBR options* select the Windows 7 partition for *Partition booted by the MBR* option. Then click the *Apply* button.

Snapshots showing the various options available in the BootRepair utility/disk:

[image: snap1]

[image: snap2]

[image: snap3]

[image: snap4]

[image: snap5]