# Windows 7 is not booting even it is showing an option in ubuntu boot menu

Tags: 12.04

I install Ubuntu 12.4 LTS with windows 7 on my Machine. But when press enter on windows 7 which was showing in boot menu of Ubuntu, it does nothing just come back to menu. Apparently Ubuntu boots perfectly fine, please help how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would Recommend you to install boot-repair in your Ubuntu as per the instructions given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc).

Then you could run and check the option to repair windows files from the application menu.