# Can't get pass the GRUB menu on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, upgrade

I can't boot to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS;I get a blinking curso and my caps key led keeps flashing.
I've tried recovery mode and it gives thesame error.I've tried loading previous version from the grub menu and have thesame error. It all started a week ago when I upgraded from 11.10 to UBUNTU 12.04 LTS and in the final stages of the upgrade i noticed that my screen had gone blank as usual when you leave your computer unattended for a while.When I moved the mouse it prompted for the password as usual but when I entered the password I couldn't get to the desktop.  the windows partition runs normally.

The error is as follows :
251.908847 KERNEL PANIC NOT SYNCING : ATTEMPTING TO KILL INIT
251.908862 PID 1, COMM : INIT NOT TAINTED 2.6.38-8-generic #42 - ubuntu

DRDY ERR 
ERROR {UNC} 
etc ----

I tried running apt-get update using live cd and got thesame error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with booting problems then use the live cd to install boot-repair by following the instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)