# Installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 on win8 64 bit machine

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, system-installation

I have a Lenovo laptop with Windows8 64 bit working fine. But I wanted to install Ubuntu.

I have done the following still I am unable to install:

1. Disabled **SecureBoot** from BIOS menu.
2. Disabled **FastBoot**.
3. '**UEFI first'** option selected.
4. A formatted drive for Ubuntu installation is also present.

I have extracted the `.iso` file to USB pen drive. On clicking on Wubi it starts downloading a `.xz` file which would take about 5hrs.
So I downloaded the Wubi file again from http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/wubi.exe.

Now on clicking to install, it asks me whether to reboot now or later. On clicking reboot now, it does reboot but goes straight to Windows 8.
Further, if I change Boot device priority order and set my USB drive to the topmost, it does not go to Windows 8, instead it lands me to a terminal like page, labelled GRUB menu, I tried to do something with different commands but to no help.

(I previously was able to dual boot my same laptop with both win8 and Ubuntu 12.04.2 working perfectly, but then my hard disk had some problem and all its content deleted; now win8 is working fine but can't install Ubuntu, I also tried Fedora.)

Answer (score 0):

Then you should try wube for windows as a last option if you need it so badly.
I installed ubuntu by CD but after updates it dosn't boot on start-up. And then I finally used wube it has some pitfalls also. 
http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.com/2011/05/installing-wubi-common-problems.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are having some problems with your boot loader.Then I would recommend you to install [boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc) as per the instructions given using a live cd of ubuntu.

Comment: but my win8 is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [unetbootin](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/&ei=xBTxUquALIrTrQfklYGIAg&usg=AFQjCNFG2iJy14ueI6PKA0HBkn1cP-KoBg&sig2=igEkYDDQGZVyItIVI5dbVQ) to make your usb bootable and select your usb drive(UEFI) from your boot options in your BIOS menu then you can disable all others and try once more

Comment: even after using unetbootin, same thing is happening. It goes straight to the terminal black screen which says 
"GNU GRUB version 1.90-21ubuntu3.10

Minmal BASH-like editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completion. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completion"