# How can I restore my desktop after updating?

Tags: 12.04, boot, graphics

After 7 updates to Ubuntu 12.04 on my pc this evening, re-start produced a black screen with `grub>` and a flashing cursor. How do I get the normal desktop back?

Comment: can give a bit more specific info? what did you update? and what is your video card? add the output of `lspci | grep VGA` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `grub` is dead. Dunno why but it is.

You can reinstall grub with a live-session (usb or dvd) and follow the directives given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc).

This will guide you through the installation of boot-repair under a live-session. With that application, you'll be able to fix your grub.