# Why can't I dual-boot with windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: dual-boot, vaio

I've installed Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 in my Sony Vaio SVS13A1S9ES and I haven't had any problems during the installation. However, when I turn on the computer, I boot with Windows 8.1 and I'm never asked if I want to boot with Ubuntu.

I've been looking for solutions: I've tried to disable the Secure Boot of Windows but this option doesn't appear in BIOS menu. I neither can boot manually pressing F11 because when I do it the following message appears: "operative system not found".

The only way I've found to boot with Ubuntu is by inserting the Super Grub2 Disk CD. The problem is that I usually have to change between Ubuntu and Windows so I wouldn't like to carry a CD everywhere to do it.

Is there any solution for dual-booting without an external device?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you red through [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that the Windows 8.1 secure boot feature complicates life. I had a similar problem in that I only got Ubuntu, not Windows. However, I believe the solution I found suggested on several sites would apply in either case, assuming the approach in the previous post did not.

When you are in Ubuntu (I gather you can get in wi,th some difficulty) install "boot-repair" as follows: Openl Terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and enter the three following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

Open boot repair from your dash and select “Recommended repair”. From there on I merely did as I was told. ON restart, the Grub did its job.

Source: Numerous, among them this one: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried to install boot-repair yesterday and got an error. Because of your answer I've tried to install it again and now it worked! (I guess that's what informatics is about).
Finally my problem is solved. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, I've had some problems with the commands that you've written. The "apt-get update" has failed. I've used this ones:

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair   ;

sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list   ;

sudo apt-get update    ;

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair   ;

I've found them in the following link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you already haven't.

Turning off secure boot depends on the make and model of your computer as each one has slightly different methods for turning it off.

Basically though click on the "super" key (Windows key) and then click on the power icon next to your user name.

Hold down the shift key on your keyboard and select restart computer. Keep the shift key held down until your computer reboots.

You will now have an option to go into your UEFI boot settings.

Within the UEFI settings look for the option to turn off secure boot. You don't have to switch to legacy mode and you shouldn't switch to legacy mode as this will not help your cause.

Save and exit the UEFI settings if all went well then

Log into Windows and make sure you are viewing the desktop and not the tiles screen.

Hover the mouse in the bottom left corner and right click. You should see an option for the administrator's command prompt. Click on this option.

Within the administrator's command prompt type the following command:

bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

Exit the command prompt.

if all went well then reboot into ubuntu.
Reboot your computer.

This time when the computer boots you should see 4 options.

1. Ubuntu
2. Ubuntu (advanced)
3. Windows (might say something similar like Windows boot options).
4. Setup

Choose option 1.

Ubuntu 14.04 should now appear.

To read the entire article goto http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I've tried this. When I reboot pressing shift and I access to the menu, I go to: "solve problems" --> "advanced options" but then, the option "Firmware UEFI configuration" doesn't appear. (I don't know if the options are named like this, I did a literal translation from Spanish, the language my PC is installed with). 
It seems to be quite strange and it has given me some head-aches. But now the problem is solved (1st comment). 
Anyway, thank you very much for your answer.