# Unable to boot Windows 7 and 8 after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 triple boot.

I already had windows 7 and 8 before installing Ubuntu. Now I am unable to boot either of them.

On startup Ubuntu is getting started directly without any triple boot option. What should I do to open either of the two windows? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please run `sudo fdisk -l` and add this information to your question.

Comment: Do you see the GRUB menu if you try to boot by holding `Ctrl` and `Shift`?

Comment: I can see GRUB menu by holding ctrl and shift . But it returns only three options: 1. Ubuntu 2. Advanced options for Ubuntu 3. System startup

Comment: Can you run in a terminal **sudo update-grub** ???

Answer (score 1):

use Boot-Repair tool to solve this problem

This [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) could be helpful for you.

To know how to install the Boot- Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc, click [here](https://www.askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)