# I'm not getting GRUB menu

Tags: boot

I installed ubuntu as second os(I have windows 8 built-in) on my Sony Vaio svf219, but my pc directly boots into windows 8 without asking specific os to  boot.Please Help me to solve this out.
Thanks In Advance and Sorry for My Bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please boot to your live cd or usb and open a terminal and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Then open dash and search for boot repair

Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

You can find more details of this [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)