# how to not install boot-repair in live every time?

Tags: boot-repair

Whenever I boot into live mode and have to run a tool like `boot-repair` I have to go the whole 9 yards to get it. The reason being that the live cd/dvd/usb doesn't come with boot-repair. Hence whenever I live boot, I have to install it once more.

What is the alternative to this [usual process](https://askubuntu.com/a/226064/1123)?

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd), might help.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you asked!  The USUAL solution is to download and burn a BOOT REPAIR cd.  I have several and have used several flavors.  I have two favorites for different reasons, but by far my most favorite is naturally the one which successfully boots the most computers.  I posted a link to it on this site just a few days ago.  Let's see if I can find it again.

http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

Comment: FYI, there is only 1 flavor of Boot-Repair-Disk (the link you have posted), in 32 or 64bit. Probably you are referring to old versions of the ISO, but they come with old versions of the Boot-Repair utility, so I do not recommend to use them.

Comment: @LovinBuntu, I'm referring to an entirely different bootable CD containing the referenced boot repair utility.  The one I referred to was essentially an installable Ubuntu Live boot CD to which a few utilities had been added, notably the boot repair utility.  What's great about it is that unlike the sourceforge one linked above, its UNITY desktop was entirely familiar to any ubuntu user and it had features such as gparted built in.  What's bad about it is that it took longer to boot.  http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/Download

Comment: ok thx. fyi ubuntu-rescue-remix is abandoned since 2012, so its Boot-Repair packages are obsolete.

Comment: @LovinBuntu, I could be misremembering about the name, but _I_swear_ that in one of my toolboxes I have a mini-dvd Ubuntu Live disc containing a version of Ubuntu (with unity desktop) 13.10 which has installed upon it the boot repair utility.  I burned it myself from an ISO file I downloaded from someplace.  The revision of Ubuntu pretty much ensures it is not something abandoned in 2012.  I will try to find it and the associated ISO file and get back to you.

Comment: I guess it was [Linux-Secure-Remix](https://sourceforge.net/p/linux-secure/wiki/Home/). The 13.10 version is obsolete, so I have removed it from the download page. I will try to create a new ISO asap.

Comment: @LovinBuntu, when you say a new ISO, do you mean of the 13.10 version, because I believe I still have the old ISO of that in my backups if you want it.  Perhaps you mean you would like to make a modern 14.04 version of it?

Comment: yes, I plan to create a 14.04 version of it, with up-to-date packages of the Boot-Repair utility. The 13.10 ISO is obsolete because it contains obsolete packages of the Boot-Repair utility.