# ubuntu14.04 can not enter ubuntu when i choose 'ubuntu' in grub2 menu

Tags: 14.04, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in hard disk.
then after I did `update-grub`

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

After restarting Ubuntu 14.04, grub menu loaded with ubuntu，ubuntu advance，system setup.
When I choose ubuntu option, it seems that ubuntu can not start, does something wrong with grub2? here are the some screenshots. 
since i don't have enough reputation to post picture,please click the url below to see the issue screenshot,thanks a lot/

[image]
[image]this is the screenshot,when i edit ubuntu option

Answer (score 1):

Try boot-repair from live cd or live USB media.

Here are the instructions :
[How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)

> 1. Insert or connect the Ubuntu live media (DVD or USB).
> 2. Find out how to [boot your computer from removable media](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD).
>
>    Note that there is a [difference between booting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Identifying_if_the_computer_boots_the_Ubuntu_DVD_in_EFI_mode) of older
>      computers (BIOS/MBR) and newer ones designed for Windows 8 and later
>      releases (UEFI/GPT).
>
>    Reboot the computer from live media and choose **Try Ubuntu** when
>      asked.

[image: Try Ubuntu]

> 3. Connect to the internet, then open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, paste the following
>      commands and run them by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:
>
>    ```
>    sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair; \
>    sudo apt-get update; \
>    sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
>    ```
>
>    > Note: You copy and run them all at once. If you want to run them individually just remove the trailing "`; \`".
>
>    That's it, the Boot-Repair window will appear!

[image: Boot-Repair main window]