# need help for booting menu after installation of ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu alongside windows 8 successfully but when i restart the machine the boot loader is not going for the option for either Ubuntu or windows 8 . It will directly load windows.
Ubuntu is fully installed on my laptop but the option is not shown to enter into Ubuntu ..
please help me out from this situation.

Comment: Silly question but did you install Grub?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [boot-repair](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/).

First create a bootable live USB of `boot-repair` and launch it on your computer.

When the boot-repair windows appear, select "**Recommended repair**". When it is done reboot your pc and see if grub appear now.

If it still directly boot to Windows, restart the `boot-repair` live USB, select "**Create a BootInfo summary**" and post the result in your question.

Comment: but actually all the files of ubuntu are present in the hard disk but when i boot from pendrive it shows all the the files even grub is also appear .