# restoring grub file

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Yesterday when i restarted my computer it is showing screen with error :

> No bootable devices found

So I am trying to restore my grub file using [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc) but my boot repair doesn't have both options as shown in the answer. It looks like this :

[image: boot-repair schreenshot]

and Paste from boot-repair  is : http://paste.ubuntu.com/12243513/

How to proceed now?

Answer (score 0):

You need the Universe repositories to install `gksu`. Therefore

Open <kbd>Software and Updates</kbd> and use the first tab <kbd>Ubuntu Software</kbd> and select the line <kbd>Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)</kbd>

[image]

After that, install the package via:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Now start `boot-repair` again.

---

Or the terminal way:

Open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and check the following lines to use the universe repositories:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
```