# Double Ubuntu, How to specify which one to boot

Tags: 14.04, 14.10

I have installed two versions of Ubuntu, 14.04 and 14.10. However, when booting I found no choose about which version to boot, and it automatically goes into Ubuntu 14.10. Do you know where I can specify it?

Comment: How did you install 2 versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can hold "right shift" during boot for the GRUB menu to appear and select what to boot from there.
2. Install "grub optimizer". It will let you edit the configuration for GRUB and let you set a time-out for the GRUB menu. If you make that longer the menu will always appear and you can select what to start. It will also let you set what to show in the menu; the older Ubuntu might be hidden from the current GRUB menu.

   It will currently be set to hide the menu and boot the last one or boot the newest one. If the 2 Ubuntu version are not there see #3.

   Installation:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
   ```
3. It could be that GRUB was not correctly informed about the dual Ubuntu boot. If so "boot repair" is another option to check. See the accepted answer here [How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc) how to install the PPA and an image on how it looks (skip the part about using the Live)

Comment: Grub customizer is Okay for me

Answer (score 2):

You need to hold the right Shift key when booting in order for the Grub menu to appear.

You can check Grub information at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: Actually I can see the Grub menu, because I installed Windows alongside Ubuntu, grub menu will automatically appear when booting. The problem is there is only a single Ubuntu in the menu.

Comment: That might be due to grub hiding the older ubuntu. editted it into my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yaunnu/boot-repair
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
 boot-repair
```

and then choose custom repair, and it might work fine this way.