# Installed Ubuntu and Windows 10, redundant entries in boot menu

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I got a computer with Windows 10. After installing Ubuntu along Windows 10 and fixing the boot sector with `boot-repair`, I ended up with this for the 1st time:

[image: grub menu]

It does work when I choose the 1st or 2nd last ones. But how to delete all those redundant items?

Answer (score 4):

### Removing & modifying grub entries

**Graphical way :**

Install `grub-customizer`, it will let you manage your grub entry easily:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

[image: grub customizer]

Select the entry you want to delete, click on **Remove** and when you are done do not forget to click on **Save**.

---

## In case of problem :

### Restoring deleted entries :

If you accidentally deleted the wrong entry `grub-customizer` include a function to easily restore removed entry :

[image]

---

### Restoring initial grub configuration :

*You should not need this but I write it just in case something goes wrong.*

`grub-customizer` keep a backup of your initial grub config in `/etc/grub.d/backup`.

If you accidentally messed up or want to go back to your original `grub` configuration here is what you can do :

**To fix an unbootable configuration, run:**

```
sudo cp /etc/grub.d/backup/boot_grub /boot/grub
```

**To reset the whole configuration, also copy these files:**

```
sudo cp /etc/grub.d/backup/etc_grub_d /etc/grub.d
sudo cp /etc/grub.d/backup/default_grub /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

(Taken from `/etc/grub.d/backup/RESTORE_INSTRUCTIONS`)

---

If you still can not managed manage to restore your grub configuration after that, follow this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/q/226061/338915).

---

Refer [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/grub-customizer/+faq/1355) for more information.

Comment: If you later want to resurrect an item, how do you do it (assuming you've rebooted multiple times since deleting)?

Comment: It would be hard if you have not made a backup of your grub config file. You can try to use `grub-repair`.  You should ask a new question, you will maybe find better solutions ;)

Comment: @Ruslan Take a look at 7) [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134)

Comment: Yeah, that seems to answer my question. It seems your answer would be more complete if you included the instructions on restoring defaults in it.

Comment: I will add it ;)

Comment: If things get totally borked and you can't boot at all, boot up a LiveUSB and run [`boot-repair`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) (may need to install via `apt-get install boot-repair` first).  It will fix your Grub menu and ensure your operating systems are all visible.

Comment: which one can I safely delete?

Comment: You can safely delete anything. In your case you can just keep `Ubuntu` and `Windows Boot Manager` (if this one boot fine) for example.

Comment: @cl-netbox, ookkkkkeyyy, okkkkeyyyyyy my friend.

Comment: I'm fine, how about you? Where did you go today?

Comment: @hg8, what a nice day!