# Can't choose to boot either windows 8.1 or ubuntu on uefi

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, uefi, windows-8, vaio

I use a Sony Vaio SVF14212 with windows 8 pre-installed. I removed Windows 8 and installed windows 8.1.

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS(I want to have dual boot ubuntu-windows), but when it restarted, it always boot windows 8.1 directly without 'show' option to choose OS. What should I do?

Comment: Please try http://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Are you running UEFI or BIOS boot? (If you don't know, boot an Ubuntu LiveDVD, choose `Try Ubuntu`, run `gparted` and post a screen shot of that.) [edit] your answer to reflect this additional information and then drop me a note @Fabby.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the BIOS and change the boot order. Ubuntu probably installed a boot manager if everything went well.

I'm not sure what the key is in Sony's laptops, but you must press one of the F1-F12 keys when the Vaio logo appears when you start up your computer.