# How to boot Ubuntu physical partition via VirtualBox on Windows

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox

I have a dual-boot setup: Windows 10 & Ubuntu 15.04. I want to be able to boot my Ubuntu partition from Windows 10 in Virtualbox. I found [this article](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-dual-boot-and-virtualize-the-same-partition-on-y-493223329) which is a couple of years old, but people apparently had success with the method.

I've gone through the steps of creating a `.vmdk` pointer to my partition and creating the `boot.iso` file, but my VirtualBox continues to say `FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.`

Here is how my VirtualBox Storage settings are configured:

[image: VirtualBox Storage Settings]

I can't find any other information about this topic (although there is plenty about booting Windows in VB from Ubuntu.

**Any ideas on how I can get this setup working?**

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is sufficient to access the Ubuntu partition through a virtual machine. Still, this partition is not the boot partition of your real machine, and the MBR of the boot loader Grub will likely not be installed on that partition but on the master boot drive.

To overcome this we may create a small additional boot drive in your virtual machine. Install Grub to this partition from a live system and let it point to booting Ubuntu from your real Ubuntu partition. This can also be done from [Boot Repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc).

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. I should create another storage device (.iso) in my virtual machine. Then, I should run Boot Repair from my live partition of Ubuntu? I think I'm getting lost by `Install Grub to this partition from a live system and let it point to booting Ubuntu from your real Ubuntu partition.`