# Installed Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10, but it won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, windows-10

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I wanted to install it on my laptop (ASUS, running Windows 10 (upgrade from Windows 8.1), Intel i5 processor, 6GB Ram, 300GB storage).

I followed instructions from the Ubuntu website and made a bootable USB using the Universal USB Installer from pendrivelinux. I booted the USB through BIOS, and clicked install Ubuntu on my computer.

When I did, this I only had the option to install it alongside Windows 8 (?). I figured it might be ok to try this, so I clicked continue, and gave it 100GB for a partition. Installed pretty quickly, and all seemed ok. I got a message saying to restart, then remove USB and click enter. All good so far.

However, on rebooting, the laptop went straight to my Windows 10 login page, and when I check the boot options on BIOS, there is no option to boot Ubuntu. However, if I boot USB again, then it says Ubuntu is installed, and I have an option to erase the Ubuntu install and reinstall it.

I know I've messed up somewhere, I just don't really know what I'm doing. Any help would be appreicated.

Cheers.

Comment: I've recently bought an ASUS X555LA which is a laptop and sounds similar to yours. It came with Windows 8 which immediately upgraded itself to 10. I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on it as dual boot without problems. I am not sure this is a definitive solution but this is what I did: In Bios turned off 'fast boot and 'csm' under the boot tab and also turned off 'secure boot' under the security tab. (After a period of reflection I decided that I hate Windows10 and then shrank its partition size down to something very small). If I had my time again, I would have had Ubuntu overwrite it completely.

Comment: I also installed it from a USB, as you did.

Comment: I have actually decided to just get rid of windows and take my chances with ubuntu - I use it on my work computer, so I know I like it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to repair the bootloader using boot repair  .
first shutdown the pc and inesrt the booted usb in pc port and start the pc 
then option to install/try the ubuntu come.
 click on try 
login to ubuntu 
after login.

1. open terminal (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or go to dash and type terminal)
2. `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair;`
3. `sudo apt-get update;` 
 4 `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

use can follow the procedure given by LovinBuntu https://askubuntu.com/a/226064/427621
   after completing the procedure unplug the usb and restart the system.