# I dual boot Win10 and Ubuntu 17 and now both do not work I can NOT use the computer now

Tags: dual-boot

My pc:

```
Motherboard: H81M-A ASUS
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460 CPU @ 3.20GHz
Gpu: SAPPHIRE Radeon™ RX 460 2G D5 OC
```

I have two hard disks. In one I installed Windows 10. The other is empty. So I decided to do dual boot and install Ubuntu on it from USB 16gb flash drive. Now I'm in big trouble.

1. Windows 10 won't boot after Ubuntu install Because of this issue ([Installed Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10, but it won't boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748631/installed-ubuntu-15-10-alongside-windows-10-but-it-wont-boot))
2. Ubuntu booting but show black screen (I used unetbootin to install the Ubuntu on the USB apparently this is not good software). What's funny is that I choose the option Try Ubuntu It works perfectly. But when I choose Install Ubuntu and Install Ubuntu on the hard disk and restart the computer after the install Finish that booting but show black screen.

What am I supposed to do now? There is no operating system that I have access to for fix this problem. The only thing I have now is to run Ubuntu from the USB flash drive and try to fix this big problem.

I thought maybe create a persistent volume On the free space in the USB flash drive and download Windows 10 and install the Windows 10 on another USB flash drive (This time I'll do it right) After I do that I will have Windows 10 USB bootable and than I try to install it on one of the 2 hard disk I have.

The problem is that I do not know if it is possible to create persistent volume On the free space in USB flash drive.

Do you have any solution to my problem?

- note: I do not have any important information on both hard disks so I have no problem that all the information on both discs will be deleted I just want the computer back.

Comment: Try to use the boot option `nomodeset` and/or maybe some other boot option too, when booting the installed Ubuntu. See this link, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808 and links from it (how to enter a boot option).

Comment: 1) Windows problem repaired in the usual way. 2) https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu black screen may by due to display driver errors. The Ubuntu installer's startup portion is sometimes incompatible with certain graphics cards. Fixing it and getting to the Ubuntu Desktop to try or install it can often be surprisingly easy fix: the nomodeset parameter.

Immediately after the BIOS splash screen during boot, press and hold the SHIFT button. This will display you grub containing a list of kernels and recovery options

[BIOS Splash Screen like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bukeH.png)

Press e to edit the first kernel displayed

Find the line ending with quiet splash. Add your boot option before these key words - i.e. so the line looks like [...]nomodeset quiet splash
Press CTRL + X to boot

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llAQz.png)

Follow the steps in [Coldfish's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782) answer on how to fix the nomodeset boot option permanently so that you don't have to go through this manual procedure again.

Comment: in tails os It is possible to store files on the free space of the usb (crate persistent volume) how i do it in Ubuntu USB  flash drive?

Comment: @johncopper did you even look? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent