# how to enable dual booting after install ubuntu in Windows Machine?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, mint

I Installed Ubuntu on my windows laptop in separate partition.
I did swap root and home partition for ubuntu and separate partition.    after installing i cant able to login to my windows OS..

please help me to enable  the dual boot grub page.... My windows version is windows 7 which installed in partition C, and i installed ubuntu on Partition D.

how to enable the grub dual os select page?

Comment: try boot-repair Try this or anything else on google.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're into Ubuntu, open up a Terminal window (CTRL + ALT + T) and run sudo update-grub. This should update your GRUB boot menu and detect partitions of other OSes.
If you want to edit the GRUB boot menu config, you can do so by opening Terminal:
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
and to apply your changes run sudo update-grub.
Restart your PC and you should see the GRUB menu.