# Grub Failing to install - Installation crashes

Tags: grub2, gparted, bootloader, 16.04

I have tried multiple times to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Mac Book Pro 2011 with a TakeMS SSD and a Hitachi HDD.

The problem is though that it copies files fine, but as soon as it gets to GRUB, the installer fails and crashes. This has meant I had to go into GParted and clean the drive.

I am installing the Whole system and Boot loader on the SSD and I think this is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug and this is affecting multiple users. I figured out an work around to install any flavour of Ubuntu 16.04 as this bug is present in all of them.

Bug is related to grub so,

1. Install Ubuntu 16.04 as usual (yes do this)
2. Wait for Installer to crash
3. As Installer crashes shut your PC down.
4. Create a Ubuntu 14.04 live USB or use CD.
5. Perform boot-repair then restart.

For boot-repair follow : [How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)

Note : Perform boot repair in live mode, don't install ubuntu 14

Comment: Any particular reason to use 14.04 for the boot-repair?  I have only been able to boot 16.04 with my new hardware.

Comment: ah, there was some problem in installing grub, so there must be some problem with it therefore, I used grub from 14.04, that's all.

Comment: this problem is also in Ubuntu Budgie 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem  upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16 earlier today. Error message says cant install bootloader (Grub) on /sda. Several options given but no matter what selected the install program will not respond to an option and pressing ok on the menu. Only way out (for me) was to crash the install program  by a HW reboot.  I also think its a bug.

Comment: yeah i have remade the usb stick again and it dosent work this with need either a 16.04.1 out soon or a boot loader fix

Answer (score 1):

When it asks for **Force UEFI Installation?**, just click **Go Back**. That did the trick for me. This is only if you are having problems with UEFI and BIOS mode compatibility issue.