# minimal bash line editing error in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: grub2, ppa, boot-repair

I tried this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc) but I got the following errors:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

and even this doesn't seem to work,

```
nano /etc/apt/source.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-saucy.list
```

I got the following error,

```
[ Error writing /etc/apt/source.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-saucy.list: No such file or directory ]
```

Is there any other alternative like adding the repository with other distribution of ubuntu?

**Update**: Report of boot-repair
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByP5h3h0_JHNeDBFRmFwZEhtWGc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Unfortunately Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) is no longer supported, and the yannubuntu PPA does not include packages for it. You may find some helpful information in [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) however I suspect you will have more success running boot-repair from a Ubuntu live disk or a dedicated [boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/)

Comment: @steeldriver I used boot-repair disk, and I have the following report. Yet ubuntu didn't boot up, I got the same minimal bash-like... error.
The report is updated in the question

Comment: I suck at interpreting boot-repair reports - however, AFAIK you don't appear to have a Linux system on the disk (`1 disks with OS, 1 OS : 0 Linux, 0 MacOS, 1 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.`) Was this perhaps a WUBI installation?

Comment: @steeldriver oops!, now I realise, I have formatted the partition which had ubuntu installed, but I have the backup of the most of the stuff, what shall I do?

Comment: Probably best to start with a clean install of a currently-supported release, and restore your files from the backup

Comment: @steeldriver Yeah, I'm doing a fresh installation.