# Dual boot option menu

Tags: grub2, menu

I installed Windows 7 and 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my PC and both worked very smoothly. Since I updated by ubuntu last month, the system starts directly to ubuntu OS.  I can't see GRUB menu, which normally appears asking for windows or ubuntu OS boot option.

Comment: - Use "boot repair" to re-install Grub.  - If you press a key during boot when grub should appear it should show up and wait a couple of seconds. http://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc

Answer (score 2):

install the grub customiser from synaptic package manager or ubuntu software Center .By using grub customizer you can load the grub and save it.

Thanks :)

Comment: I'd be wary of using Grub Customizer

Comment: Why? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @pfeiffep have u installed it yet???

Comment: @SudipDas Yes I installed it quite some time ago - it caused me many hours to unscramble the mess it made of my multi-boot system. If I'm unable to make Grub adjustments manually I just accept the results provided. I'll NEVER use the customizer again.

Comment: @pfeiffep yes u can also fix it by using live boot....bt u r telling me that it had been taken many hour for u  bt for me it takes only 1 or 2 min ....

Comment: @SudipDas In my situation I had 4 different OSes installed, using the Grub Customizer scrambled Grub to the extent I had to use the terminal to get a working grub install.

Comment: @pfeiffep ya...may be for that reason .... :)

Answer (score 2):

Hold down the SHIFT key when booting, and you should see the GRUB menu, where you can select which OS to boot.

Depending on how your GRUB is configured, it will remember the last choice you made in GRUB, or it won't, and you'll have to select Windows every time. More detail available if required.

Cheers, Al

Comment: I tried to boot my system by pressing the SHIFT Key when booting.  I saw that GRUB menu, but the Windows OS option was missing.  How can I select  which OS to boot.

Comment: It sounds like you need to reinstall GRUB. It's easy. Go ahead and boot into Ubuntu. Open terminal, and type "sudo update-grub", and it'll ask for your password. That should fix the missing Windows selection. If for some reason that you still have a problem, we'll discuss using a program called Boot Repair. Cheers, Al

Comment: I was trying this way for a long time since you suggested it.  But the problem of dual boot option missing is still there.  Whenever I tried the terminal shows the following :-

Comment: Your last comment was missing something. Did you already do the `sudo update-grub`? If so, start `Synaptic` from the dash. First click the `reload` icon. Then search for `boot-repair`. You'll get 3 results. Mark all 3 for installation. When done, open `Boot Repair` from the dash and click the `recommended repair` button. See if that fixes things for you. Cheers, Al