# Grub don't work after latest Win10 update

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I had dual-boot with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10. After last Win10 update, my grub disappeared and I am booting straight to Windows. I wanted to repair it, but I also wanted to update my Ubuntu to 16.04. I updated Ubuntu from USB but it still booted straight to Win. I went to live ubuntu and tried boot-repair, but no luck. I also tried the procedure described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows). I did not get any error messages but the system still loads directly to Windows. I have secure boot disabled and I have HDD partition first in boot order in BIOS before Windows Boot Manager. I have also run the bcdedit command in Windows. Any ideas?

Comment: That's Microsoft for you! They don't care if they break people's dual-boots.

Comment: Windows anniversary update : deleted ubuntu : no grub then : reallocate memory from disk management : install again

Comment: @minigeek Can you elaborate? If I understand you correctly I should put my USB in, choose option "Other", delete the Ubuntu partition, then allocate it again?

Comment: @piko.. windows anniversary update when done online deleted ubuntu or grub (many cases) . check in disk management of windows if there are any Linux partitions available or they are merged with windows disk..if they are not there...then unallocate some disk from it(i m talking about windows) and install Ubuntu into it...if This is not the case then search for installing grub instead of repairing it

Comment: If you are trying to repair grub..if ubuntu is deleted..then no point in repairing grub..if ubuntu is not there!

Comment: The ubuntu partition is there. I also updated to 16.04 today, but without grub I can't access it.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong file in bcdedit command. The right command is:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Comment: Are you saying that this fixed your problem?

Comment: This did not work for me. You could try to use `shimx64.efi` instead of `grubx64.efi`. If that does not work either, you need to reinstall GRUB using boot-repair as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc