# Ubuntu Boot-Repair in USB

Tags: boot-repair

I was going through this thread:

[How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)

I just want to add Boot-Repair to my USB stick along with Ubuntu ISO.

How can I do that?

Comment: I believe what @karel is implying is that you don't need to.

Comment: Right, you can make the Ubuntu live USB in the usual way and then boot from it and install Boot-Repair on the Ubuntu live USB.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Boot-Repair to the Ubuntu on the disk as long as it is a persistent Ubuntu install, (**mkusu**).

Boot the disk open terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

If you want a disk that boots Ubuntu and Boot-Repair separately try **MultiBootUSB**.

Comment: Note that boot-repair ppa is not available for all ubuntu distributions. For example v19.04  (disco dingo) has not so apt-get install will not find it. Solution: Configure sooftware sources, and replace disco by groovy (or other distro with ppa packages)   https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair