# window 10 ubuntu 16.04 dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot

Iam new to linux. I tried installing Ubuntu 16.04  with Windows 10 choosing the installation option for Ubuntu to dual-boot alongside Windows Boot Manager. The installation ran smoothly and I restarted my computer. It restarted and booted window 10. i tried to reinstalled again, restarted this time booting ubuntu.

Comment: It's a boot record issue, very common. Please try boot-repair http://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc#226064

Answer (score 0):

As one option you can just reinstall the linux bootloader and have the selection of what to boot made in the linux loader. I have that on all my systems and it works stable with Win10, Win7 and WinXP.

For this to work you should install the grub2 on the disk rather than the partition. On standard BIOS it will put itself into the Master Boot record (MBR). If you have a running Linux installation you could try it out with

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

It will need your password. That does two things
*checks your drive for any bootable partitions
*Creates a new boot loader on the disk
A boot loader on the partition will be replaced by other boot code.

Now you should at least see a windows boot option. If that fails, i.e. "bootmgr" missing, you still need the windows install cd, enter repair mode and execute the automatic repair up to 3 times. just search for ""bootmgr missing" for a wide choice of tutorials.

An advantage of that option is that fixing grub is very quick and does not require a repair CD. I need to do it when I restore images or partitions from backup or other computers and it is quite quick.

A disadvantage is that the setup of grub2 has become more complicated than it has been with the old grub (I call it grub1). The old had a config file, you google for what option you need, copy&paste it in and voila. The new you need to change script files and its a bit cryptic for a windows person. Luckily I rarely need to do it and on AskUbuntu its quick to find a step-by-step guide on what to do.

If you are confused and want to stick with Linux, its a good thing to browse about the grub and boot process. This will not be wasted knowledge.