# Trying to Run a dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

So I have a lot of partitions on my computer. (came partitioned with the backup and then windows 10 created more). I just installed Linux on my dual boot. I can run both Windows 10 and Linux perfectly. The issues is this though.
In order to install from USB I had to boot legacy. Now when I boot legacy I see the grub menu and it has Linux and some Windows 10 restore partitions but not the actual windows 10 os. In order to switch between the two I have to go into bios click boot to UEFI first and then windows. Boot into legacy first boom Linux. Anyone know how to fix this so that Grub shows both.

The grub that I installed was part of the linux install.

I know there are multiple dual boot topics but i haven't seen one mentioning legacy and UEFI and i am not sure if that is what is messing me up.

Comment: Boot repair is a good option: http://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc

Comment: should i run that in windows or in linux?

Comment: any way to get this without having a live cd with it?

Comment: If I remember correctly, in your situation, switching to UEFI might get you unable to boot to either. This tool(run a usb drive) tries to recover both(80-90% success).

Comment: You'll need a live session. I don't think there's any other way

Comment: i can boot into uefi and get my windows 10 working fine. currently on it

Comment: If you run Boot Repair, as lamino suggests, be sure to do it *from an EFI-mode boot* of an Ubuntu emergency disk. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for more details on why enabling BIOS/CSM/legacy support was a mistake and what you should have done instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have UEFI and legacy boot at the same time which causes the problem.

Actually, you do not need to switch to legacy boot when installing Ubuntu. Make sure the USB partition format is **FAT32**, write bootable image to USB device and UFEI bios should be able to recognize it.

You may try re-generating grub menu (google...), but I think **reinstalling** linux is good choice.

Comment: i booted into legacy first when i installed linux. as long as i select legacy first grub comes up with linux option. when i select uefi first (in bios setup) it loads windows.

Comment: @Searim It acted as it should be. You could try `easybcd` in windows 10 to add a boot entry in windows bootmanager menu. btw, I recommend you switch to GPT partition table, it's much more convenient than MBR.