# No bootable devices ubuntu 14.04 dual boot with win7

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I am having dual boot ubuntu 14.04 and Win7.

1. I found that one of my drive in my laptop had ard 200gb with Windows for other erp applications which i was not using so i opened gparted in live usb and deleted that partition thinking i will use that free space for my ubuntu 14.04 which was running out of space. I also unswaped one ubuntu partition before gpart deletion of that.
2. I got that 200GB as unallocated but thought will increase /home later so came out.
3. When i rebooted my system i lost my grub. I could see hd0,msdos5 as my ext2 bootable drive but when i entered insmod normal then it said no such file.
4. Tried several forums and used fixboot in bootrec.This created a new problem that i am now getting error No bootable devices --strike F1 to retry boot , F2 for set up etc.
5. Through F2 i  moved my HDD to top but no result.

I am having live ubuntu 14.04 to boot and would like to move ahead with that to recover grub (not grub2)/bootable device and use my ubuntu and win7 per choice.

Please suggest.
shaukatkhan

Comment: Sorry, this is very confusing. Assuming you installed in BIOS mode, the first thing to do know is to recover the Windows bootloader so you can boot Windows and do other repairs. Then you can boot a Ubuntu live session, check the partitions and if needed reinstall Ubuntu. So, come back if you need help with the Ubuntu part, after recovering Windows.

Comment: Is it possible to get my grub using live Ubuntu USB?

Comment: You mention grub (grub legacy) not grub2. But grub2 has been standard for Ubuntu since 2009. How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7/8/10 BIOS bootloader 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader and 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Comment: I used following using Live USB stick and then when I reboot I am getting - grub>

Comment: I used - sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt # Example: sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdX # Example: sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda

Comment: The easiest solution should be [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc

Answer (score 0):

When I got grub> prompt then I did following:

Grub> ls

Grub> set root=(hd0,msdos5)

Grub> Linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5

Grub> initrd /initrd.img

Grub> boot

Then your Ubuntu is there.

I am taking backup and then if I face any issue then will install it afresh. Will keep you posted. Thanks to all.

Comment: Hello ofred, is there a way I can get the grub menu again? As I am getting grub prompt every time I switch on my laptop?

Comment: I believe when I deleted the partition which was a primary then MBR got wiped out. Resulting in no boot.

Comment: So now I have deleted everything post backup and installed afresh.

Comment: I have reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 with Online update but I don't see any Internet neither with Wire nor with wireless. I have b43 Broad come device but since wired net is not there I am not able to bring back Internet. Please help. When I connect wire I can see icon but there is no Internet. Windows working fine with Internet.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer (✓). [Self answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) and accepting them are OK here! If you have follow-up questions, please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/961674/edit).