# Unable to resize ext4 partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I want to extend the size of ext4 but minimum and maximum size are same , what could be done ?

[image]

Comment: You need to unmount it to resize it.  The key icon next to the ext4 means it is mounted so you will not be able to resize it.  But it actually looks like you will have to boot to a LiveCD to do it as you need to move the whole sda4 to the front of the unallocated space then add to sda4, then you can resize sda6.

Comment: @Terrance could not unmount ! shows this error : # umount -v "/"
umount: /: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)

Comment: Updated my comment

Comment: @Terrance got stuck in grub rescue after using gparted live CD. ls (hd0,msdos6)/ shows no grub folder it just shows /./../lost+found/ , what to do ?

Comment: More than likely need to run the Boot Repair so that grub can be fixed for the movement of the `/` root partition.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc and run the Boot Repair on your system.

Answer (score 0):

The partition `/dev/sda6` cannot be directly partitioned:  it is  inside of the extended partition `/dev/sda4`, and `/dev/sda4` is full.

To increase the size of '/' you will need to:

- first increase the size of '/dev/sda4'
- Move the new 'unallocated space' inside '/dev/sda4' to become adjacent to (next to) '/dev/sda6'
- Increase the size of  '/dev/sda6' to include the free space.

None of this should be done *while Ubuntu is running*.  Please create a liveUSB, ***Back up your data***, and boot from the liveUSB, selecting "Try Ubuntu" when prompted.  Once booted from the USB you will be able to use `gparted` to manipulate the partitions on your disk.